# Two (or multiple) subqueries inside a case-when block

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to create a "when" block, that contain two conditions:

**specific part of the query:**

```
when (
    (
        SELECT count(distinct id)
        FROM sample_table 
        WHERE name_ IN ('sample', 'another_sample') 
        AND "data" ->> 'sample_json' = 'sample_value'
    ) >= 1
AND
    (
        SELECT count(distinct id) from sample_table 
        WHERE my_date > current_date - interval '3 years'
        AND name_ IN ('sample', 'another_sample')
        AND "data" ->> 'sample_json' = 'sample_value'
    ) = 0
) then 100
```

---

**entire cte**:

```
sample_cte as (
        select
            ot.id_customer_sample,
            ( case
when (
    (
        SELECT count(distinct id)
        FROM sample_table 
        WHERE name_ IN ('sample', 'another_sample') 
        AND "data" ->> 'sample_json' = 'sample_value'
    ) >= 1
AND
    (
        SELECT count(distinct id) from sample_table 
        WHERE my_date > current_date - interval '3 years'
        AND name_ IN ('sample', 'another_sample')
        AND "data" ->> 'sample_json' = 'sample_value'
    ) = 0
) then 100
when (
    select count(distinct id)
    from sample_table
    where my_date > current_date - interval '3 years'
    and (name_='sample' and "data" ->> 'sample_json' = 'sample_value')
    or (name_ = 'another_sample' and "data" ->> 'status' = 'sample_value')) >= 3 then 300
when (
    select count(distinct id)
    from sample_table
    where my_date > current_date - interval '3 years'
    and (name_='sample' and "data" ->> 'sample_json' = 'sample_value')
    or (name_ = 'another_sample' and "data" ->> 'status' = 'sample_value')) >= 1 then 200
else 0 end
) as score_sample

from sample_table cd
right join other_table ot on
ot.id_customer_sample = cd.id_customer_sample
and (cd.name_ = 'sample' and cd."data" ->> 'sample_json' = 'sample_value')
or (cd.name_ = 'another_sample' and cd."data" ->> 'status' = 'sample_value')
group by bp.id_customer_sample
```

But it is not returning me the result I expect for this query, am I using this statement correctly?

Comment: What does it return and what is your desired result? Also, please provide fuller SQL statement for context.

Comment: The form appears correct. You might want to use `exists` and `not exists` insteed.

Comment: @Parfait I know that are some register at the database for a certain customer that has "my_date" inside the last '3 years', but my return is being 100, when my second subquery says that I don't want any register inside the last '3 years', at 'select count(*) ... = 0' condition.

Comment: @Parfait I just provided the "full" SQL

Comment: How do you relate subqueries to outer query? All rows will evaluate the same.

Comment: @Parfait, I'm using a default join:: JOIN sample_cte ON table.id_customer_sample = sample_cte.id_customer_sample

Comment: @shawnt00 I tried but it also appeared not to work, It doesn't fit to a customer at my database. I tried: CASE WHEN ((SELECT EXISTS (...)) AND (SELECT NOT EXISTS(...))) then 100

Comment: I mean your aggregate subqueries not outer `join`. How do the inner `sample_table`s relate to outer `sample_table` aliased as `cd`? Right now *all* rows will return same `score_sample` result. Is `id` is the primary key of `sample_table`?

Comment: You have a `and` `or` problem. Do you want `(something and other thing) or new thing`? Or do you want `something and (other thing or new thing)`?

Comment: No, I don't think you're doing this correctly. You'll have better luck giving a description of how the tables relate and the problem you're solving.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comments, I think the issue is your `and` and `or`, so think like this when someone tells you, go buy me bread and milk or butter, how would you read that statement? Buy me (bread and milk) or butter? Or would you read it as buy me bread and (milk or butter)?

I believe you just need to update your query like this:

```sql
with sample_cte as (
    select ot.id_customer_sample,
        ( case
        when (
        SELECT count(distinct id)
        FROM sample_table 
        WHERE name_ IN ('sample', 'another_sample') 
        AND "data" ->> 'sample_json' = 'sample_value'
    ) >= 1
AND
    (
        SELECT count(distinct id) from sample_table 
        WHERE my_date > current_date - interval '3 years'
        AND name_ IN ('sample', 'another_sample')
        AND "data" ->> 'sample_json' = 'sample_value'
    ) = 0
 then 100
when (
    select count(distinct id)
    from sample_table
    where my_date > current_date - interval '3 years'
    and (
        (name_='sample' and "data" ->> 'sample_json' = 'sample_value')
        or (name_ = 'another_sample' and "data" ->> 'status' = 'sample_value')
    )) >= 3 then 300
when (
    select count(distinct id)
    from sample_table
    where my_date > current_date - interval '3 years'
    and (
        (name_='sample' and "data" ->> 'sample_json' = 'sample_value')
        or (name_ = 'another_sample' and "data" ->> 'status' = 'sample_value')
    )) >= 1 then 200
else 0 end
) as score_sample

from sample_table cd
right join other_table ot 
on ot.id_customer_sample = cd.id_customer_sample
and ((cd.name_ = 'sample' and cd."data" ->> 'sample_json' = 'sample_value')
    or (cd.name_ = 'another_sample' and cd."data" ->> 'status' = 'sample_value'))
group by bp.id_customer_sample
```

Maybe I don't have enough parenthesis, you can get lost in all of them ;-), but you get the idea.